# onmouseenter event wont work on div element

Tags: javascript, html, css

A part of a webpage i am designing consists of several `div` elements placed side by side. Each one contains an image. I want to summon a drop-down menu when the user's mouse enters the div. However, testing it with a simple "print hello" function didn't yield the results i was expecting.

At this point, the images are placed properly, and their size is adjusted just like i specified. However, the cursor is not `pointer`and the function `test` doesn't run when the mouse enters the div. I've had this problem with click events in the past and i always tried to find a way around it. Can someone explain why it won't work?

Here's the html

```css
#container {
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
}
#icon {
  background-color: burlywood;
  border-radius: inherit;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
#menu a {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Arial";
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#flag {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
#menu a:hover {
  color: #e55d00;
}
body {
  height: 2000px;
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
}
#btt {
  bottom: 0;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#contain {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1000px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
#sidemenu {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
  transition: width 1s;
  padding-top: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#sidemenu a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}
#sidemenu a:hover {
  color: red;
}
#language {
  margin-left: 250%;
}
#title a {
  color: #e55d00;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#title {
  font-size: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}
#projects {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
#current {
  width: 210px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#current img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
#progress {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#progress img {
  width: inherit;
  height: inherit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Projects</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="projects.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="icon">
            <img src="img.png">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="title" title="Home">
            <a href="electrocats.html">Electrocats</a>
          </div>
          <div id="menu">
            <a href="#" onclick="summonMenu()">News</a>
            <a href="projects.html">Projects</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
            <a href="#">menu item 4</a>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="language">
            <a href="#" title="Translate to Greek">
              <img id="flag" src="Greece-icon.png">
            </a>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <div id="contain">
    <div id="sidemenu" onmouseleave="hideMenu()">
      <a href="Contact.html">contact</a>
      <a href="Films.html">Films</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- here is the code with the problem -->
  <div id="projects">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="current" onmouseenter="test">
            <img src="high-voltage.png">
          </div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="progress" onmouseenter="test">
            <img src="engineering1.jpg">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>



  <a id="btt" href="#top">Back to top</a>


  <script>
    function summonMenu() {
      var menu = document.getElementById("sidemenu");
      menu.style.width = "400px";
    }

    function hideMenu() {
      var menu = document.getElementById("sidemenu");
      menu.style.width = "0";
    }

    function test() {
      console.log("hello");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is your console returning any errors?

Comment: No errors, or results whatsoever.

Comment: works just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/js8j0a1s/ - sometimes the console takes a second to display things.

Comment: What browser & version are you using?

Comment: @raphael75 I am using the latest version of chrome. I am writing the code in webstorm.

Comment: @Alan, I tested it with FF 49.0.1 (latest version) and it worked for me.

Comment: Your code works fine!

Comment: I will edit to include all the code, just in case something is wrong with the rest of it ...

Comment: Tested the entire code in jsfiddle and it didn't work, so the problem probably lies elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, setting the position of the `div` that contains the images to `absolute`solved the issue. I've yet to understand why, but i believe it has something to do with the `z-index` values specified in the css file. I would really appreciate it if someone could explain why the issue was solver this way.

Answer (score 2):

Hello See the below Fiddle Here I did this using `alert` but you can do the same using `console.log` Hope It helps you .

[Div Hover Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/yxy7ord0/2/)

also Added a fiddle with a dropdown list visible on mouse enter event what are you trying to made i guess so .

[dropdown Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/Vgj8q/545/)